# bash script: change output uniq -c

Tags: text-formatting, uniq

I have to change the output of uniq -c:
(example)

```
92 root
80 user
```

in

```
root 92
user 80
```

how can I do without using awk force?

Comment: What is wrong with awk?

Comment: Nothing I would like to know if there are other ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with GNU `sed`:

```
... | sed -E 's/(\S*) (\S*)/\2 \1/'
```

Or POSIXly,

```
... | sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)/\2 \1/'
```

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas - fwiw, none of these works with actual `uniq -c` output - the quantifier in the 1st group has to be `+` (or `\{1,\}`) to deal with the leading whitespace

Comment: @don_crissti, that would depend on the `uniq` implementation. The OP's seems to not output leading spaces. In any case, yes, using `+` would help making it work with `uniq` implementations that output leading spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with cut and paste, given your input is a file and the delimiter is a space:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 input > temp1
cut -d' ' -f2 input > temp2
paste -d' ' temp2 temp1 > output
rm temp*
```

Comment: If somebody knows how to have a tab as a delimiter in `cut` other than copy/paste i'd be very very thankful.

Comment: Try : `cut -d $'\t'`

Comment: @GillesQuenot- that is _utterly superfluous_: TAB **is the default delimiter** when using [`cut`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html) _and_ [`paste`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html)

Comment: and btw, if that `uniq -c` output is exactly as posted by the OP (no leading spaces, columns separated by a single space) and if it's saved in a file you don't need temporary files etc you can simply run: `paste -d' ' infile infile | cut -d' ' -f2,3`

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl`

```
... | perl -ane 'print "$F[1] $F[0]\n"'
```

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129123/rearrange-columns-using-cut?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#answer-22918783)